# Python get followers usernames via python selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, instagram

I try to get follower list from an acocunt but even if there are 211 followers, follower who at the end of following box has xpath :     ('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[**208**]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/span/div')
therefore I've when loop goes to above 208. Can you help me? Thank you so much. This is my first entry on stackoverflow.

**After login and click into profile that I want to investigate :
**

```
`following_panel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]')
time.sleep(5)
last_ht, ht = 0, 1
while last_ht != ht:
    last_ht = ht
    time.sleep(4)
    # scroll down and retrun the height of scroll
    ht = driver.execute_script(""" 
    arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);
    return arguments[0].scrollHeight; """, following_panel)
list_of_followings = []
i=1
while i<209:
     list_of_followings.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/span/div').text)
     i+=1

print(list_of_followings)
print("****************")`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Wait for the followers to be present on the page
following_panel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@class="PZuss"]')))

# Extract the follower names
followers = following_panel.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="PZuss"]')
list_of_followings = []
for follower in followers:
    name = follower.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/span/div').text
    list_of_followings.append(name)

print(list_of_followings)
print("****************")
```

This code will wait for up to 10 seconds for the followers to be present on the page before trying to find them.

Comment: It did not get any error and also after scroll at the and it takes long time but when it printed the list it seems empty :(

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly. Try it, i've added the "ExpectedConditions" class to wait for the followers to be present on the page :)

Comment: Unfourtanetely nothing changed still empty list :/

Comment: I'm thankful for your effort

Comment: by the way WebDriverwait doesn't work so I replaced it time.sleep(10)